# How to find this Weekend and next Weekend from the current date?

Tags: android, date

I am getting data on the the basis dates . Actually I know how to get current date . But I want to find out the This weekend date(i.e Saturday and Sunday) and Next weekend(i.e Saturday and Sunday).

I found many solution regarding weekend dates. But non of them full-fill the criteria.

Please let me know if there is any possible way.

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: You can add next 7 Days to Calendar with _Calendar.DATE_

Comment: @Vishwajit have you tried my solution?

Comment: please give me an example how can i elaborate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get Weekend Date using this function

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
c.getTime();
```

For this function you will get the current week's weekend date and add 7 to this date you will get next weekend date

Comment: i have to find both Saturday and Sunday. please give me proper solution

Comment: Thanks @Milan . the above works fine and I have also do some changes to fin next saturday and sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

```
    Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SATURDAY);
    c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY);

    //c.add(Calendar.DATE,7);
    Date thisWeekendSAT = c.getTime();
    c1.add(Calendar.DATE,7);
    Date thisWeekendSUN = c1.getTime();

    thisWeekendAsSAT = dateFormat.format(thisWeekendSAT);
    thisWeekendAsSUN = dateFormat.format(thisWeekendSUN);

    Log.d("Erroror",thisWeekendAsSAT);
    Log.d("Erroror",thisWeekendAsSUN);
```